# Contractor vs Vendor

Tags: word-choice

My company is ordering a product and/or service from another company. When stating obligations on paper, would the company doing the work, from our point of view, be better described as Vendor or as a Contractor?

What would be the fine differences between the two?

Comment: you might consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterparty as an alternative to avoid having to make the distinction at all.

Comment: @JeffSahol - We're already using both terms (sometimes interchangeably) and I would like to learn the fine difference, when to use one and when the other.

Comment: Some companies prefer to be called a "partner" rather than a "vendor" or "contractor" when working together with another company to accomplish a shared goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contractor is a kind of vendor.

*Vendor* is a relatively general term, referring to a company that sells any kind of product or service. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vendor):

> A person or company offering something for sale, especially a trader in the street

*Contractor* refers to a vendor that enters into a contract with the customer. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contractor):

> A person or firm that undertakes a contract to provide materials or labour to perform a service or do a job

So if the business involves independent transactions, the seller is just a vendor; if there's an ongoing relationship described in a contract, they're a contractor.

However, in many business-to-business situations they're used interchangeably, I think because it's understood that certain types of services are usually provided under contract, so the vendor is assumed to be a contractor.

Answer (score 1):

A vendor does not have to have a written contract. Vendor may provide a service or product requested by the customer and they submit a request for payment.  A contractor bids on a service or item and the consumer selects the best bid.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.